# How do i make the ball image bounce from one player to another?

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java and I have been asked to create a java application where a ball should bounce from one player to another. I have used arrays so that when the ball hits one of the players it will turn to the opposite side. However, everytime I run the program the ball wouldnt move. Can anyone please help me work it out thanks.

```
public void act() {

    if(direction == "right") {
        if((ballx== 6 && bally == 13) || (bally==15)){
            direction = "left";
        }
        else {
            Icon white = new ImageIcon("images/white32x32.jpg");
            Icon ball = new ImageIcon("images/ball.png");

            white_lbl[ballx][bally].setIcon(white);
            bally++;
            white_lbl[ballx][bally].setIcon(ball);

            if(bally==9) {
                Icon brick = new ImageIcon("images/bricks2.jpg");
                white_lbl[ballx][8].setIcon(brick);
            }
            else if(bally==8) {
                Icon brick = new ImageIcon("images/bricks2.jpg");
                white_lbl[ballx][7].setIcon(brick);
            }
        }
    }
    else if(direction == "left") {
        if((ballx == 6 && bally == 2) || (bally==0)) {
            direction = "right";
        }
        else {
            Icon white = new ImageIcon("images/white32x32.jpg");
            Icon ball = new ImageIcon("images/ball.png");

            white_lbl[ballx][bally].setIcon(white);
            bally--;
            white_lbl[ballx][bally].setIcon(ball);

            if (bally==7) {
                Icon brick = new ImageIcon ("images/bricks2.jpg");
                white_lbl[ballx][8].setIcon(brick);
            }
            else if (bally==6) {
                Icon brick = new ImageIcon("images/bricks2.jpg");
                white_lbl[ballx][7].setIcon(brick);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: A [mcve] would help...

Comment: May or may not be the issue, but: compare Strings with `.equals`, not wìth `==`.

Comment: You probably want to manage your direction using vectors (direction/speed) rather than strings, you don't need to wrap in direction Ifs and just have to handle changing (direction/speed) to bounce back.

Comment: And so what variable name should i change "direction" to